# Why am I getting innoDB tables in information_schema in mariaDB 10.1?

Tags: mariadb, information-schema, storage-engines

MariaDB 10.1 uses XtraDB as default engine, But I am still getting innoDB tables in information_schema . Why am I getting innoDB tables in information_schema?

Comment: You mean that the Engine column says 'Innodb' instead of 'Xtradb'?  Are there some of each?

Comment: No , In information schema if you say show tables , most of the tables are innodb tables . for eg . innodb_sys_datafiles, innodb_tablestats, etc

Answer (score 0):

Since XtraDB is a "drop-in replacement" for InnoDB, *probably* they say "innodb" in order to avoid confusion for scripts, code, etc that uses them.

(Caveat:  I can't say the above as a "fact", I have watched the evolution of XtraDB and MariaDB over the years, and feel that it is a safe guess.)

Some history...

Several years ago, Percona modified InnoDB (then 'owned' by Mysql AB or Sun, I forget the exact timing) to create XtraDB.  XtraDB had some desperately needed fixes for performance.  Since then, Oracle acquired MySQL (including InnoDB) and made numerous changes to it, especially in 5.6 and 5.7.  Some of those changes were to incorporate (or replicate) the improvements that made XtraDB so good.  Meanwhile, Percona continued development of XtraDB.  Today, good code is generated by either, and sometimes incorporated into the other.

Meanwhile, MariaDB was branching off, and making other improvements in MySQL overall.  At some point (10.x?), they chose to use Percona's XtraDB instead of Oracle's InnoDB.

To the casual observer, InnoDB and XtraDB feel, act, and smell the same.  But if you dig hard enough, you can produce a test case that works better in one than in the other.  Apples versus Oranges.

Bottom line:  Not a problem.

Comment: Yes Thanks a lot Rick.